# Struct values in array return wrong values in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I had an array of "MyStruct"

```
    typedef struct MyStruct {
            double a;
            double b;
            double c;
        }MyStruct ;

        ....
    MyStruct tab[30];
    for (i=0;i<30;i++){
        tab[i].a=1.0f;
        tab[i].b=2.0f;
        tab[i].c=3.0f;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       MyStruct s = tab[i];
          ....
       //tab[i] correct (1,2,3)
       //s incorrect (0,0,0)
    }
            ...
```

When I put a breakpoint on `MyStruct s = tab[i];` and I watch in compiler, values in tab are correct. The problem is my variable 's', s.a, s.b and s.c have not the same values that the array at index i.

I don't understand the problem

Comment: `for(int i = =;i<10;i++)` What is this?

Comment: Can you fix all the typos in your code, like that broken `for` and `tab[i]a`.

Comment: It would also be nice if you indented correctly, so it didn't look like the second loop is inside the first one.

Comment: With all the retyping you're doing, I wonder how many other differences there are from your actual code. Paste the real code.

Comment: Show code that ACTUALLY demonstrates the problem.  Ideally, use printf to actually output the values, and demonstrate that the wrong values are being shown.  (We don't all have the same debugger, and you cannot "demonstrate" your debugging steps)

Comment: Do not use the `f` suffix with double variables.  f means *float*.  You've explicitly created a float-value, which the compiler then has to convert to a double for the assigment.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the breakpoint exactly on this line:

```
MyStruct s = tab[i];
```

If that is the case, then the assignment has not occurred yet.  Step to the next line in the debugger and check the values then.

Comment: In that case can you include the code where the breakpoint is set, and all of the code in between?  It's hard to tell what it's doing wrong when we can't see what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your current code.

The only possibility could be you are checking  `s` when it comes out of scope.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    MyStruct s = tab[i];
    int x = 0; //temp code - Put break-point here and check.
    x++; //temp code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyStruct s;
memcpy(&s, tab + i, sizeof(MyStruct));
```

and your structure is correctly filled.